# MinGW treats second declaration of an object in a class as a Constructor

Tags: c++, class, object, g++, mingw

I am trying to write a class (let's call it `Bar`) that takes an object of another class (`Foo`) as an argument to the constructor. I also have an object of class `Foo` declared as an attribute of `Bar`. Here is some example code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int i) {
        std::cout << i;
    }
};

class Bar {
private:
    Foo fooObject1;

public:
    Bar(Foo fooObject2) {

    }
};

int main() {

}
```

For some reason, g++ (MinGW) seems to treat the second declaration of a `Foo` object (as an argument to the `Bar` constructor) as if it were a constructor. Trying to compile that code example gives the following error:

```
test.cpp: In constructor 'Bar::Bar(Foo)':
test.cpp:15:25: error: no matching function for call to 'Foo::Foo()'
   15 |     Bar(Foo fooObject2) {
      |                         ^
test.cpp:5:5: note: candidate: 'Foo::Foo(int)'
    5 |     Foo(int i) {
      |     ^~~
test.cpp:5:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:3:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr Foo::Foo(const Foo&)'
    3 | class Foo {
      |       ^~~
test.cpp:3:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:3:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr Foo::Foo(Foo&&)'
test.cpp:3:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

What causes this and how can I prevent this error?

Comment: What you are doing is trying to create a copy of your Foo object and pack it into Bar.
According to your compilers Output you Probably wanna write a copy constructor `Foo::Foo(const Foo&)`. Since the only Constructor you have is Foo(int) so your programm doesn't know how it is supposed to copy Foo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the declaration that is treated as constructor call, but the member `fooObject1` needs to be initialized in some way in `Bar`'s constructor. So the compiler generates some code to call the default constructor `Foo::Foo()`. But that does not exist, so you get an error.

One solution is to explicitly initialize the member in the member initializer list:

```
Bar(Foo fooObject2) : fooObject1(fooObject2) { ... }
```

The other would be to provide a default constructor for `Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

The `Bar` constructor is trying to default construct the `fooObject1` but  `Foo` does not have a default constructor.

add `Foo() = default;` to the `Foo` and it will compile.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to copy `fooObject2` to `fooObject1` (it's not very clear what you want to do). If so then this code is what you want

```
Bar(Foo fooObject2) : fooObject1(fooObject2) {

}
```